# Changed API in Android emulator, and getting SQLiteException

Tags: android, sqlite

My Android Studio got updated with 2.3.1 version, while I was working with my `project.Ad` that time, everything was perfect, and I was creating layouts for different screen size, so my app would look like the same in different size.

When I tried to see the app in an emulator. I started with Nexus 7 API 24, I got a crush when I wanted to log in, and got this error:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: user_id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT task_Id, user_id, title, content FROM Todos WHERE user_id = ?

This line:

> at com.ToDo.todoTasks.sql.DatabaseHelper.getTaskByUser(DatabaseHelper.java:149)

Is pointing to:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query
```

Which is inside

```
public ArrayList < ToDo > getTaskByUser()

public ArrayList < ToDo > getTaskByUser() {
  // array of columns to fetch
  String[] columns = {
    TASK_ID,
    user_id,
    TITLE,
    CONTENT
  };

  ArrayList < ToDo > taskList = new ArrayList < ToDo > ();

  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

  // query the user table
  SharedPreferences pref = ctx.getSharedPreferences("LOGIN", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  String userid = pref.getString("USER_NUM", null);
  Cursor cursor = db.query(
    mTODO,
    columns,
    "user_id = ?",
    new String[] {
      userid
    },
    null,
    null,
    null);

  // Traversing through all rows and adding to list
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
      ToDo todo = new ToDo();
      todo.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TASK_ID))));
      todo.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TITLE)));
      todo.setUserID(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(user_id)));
      todo.setContent(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CONTENT)));
      // Adding user record to list
      taskList.add(todo);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  cursor.close();
  db.close();

  // return user list
  return taskList;
}
```

`DatabaseHelper` class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  Context ctx;
  // Database Version
  private static final int DB_VER = 1;

  // Database Name
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";

  // User table name
  private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

  // User Table Columns names
  private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
  private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
  private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
  private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

  //Table mToDo task name
  private final static String mTODO = "Todos";

  //Todos table columns names
  private final static String TASK_ID = "task_Id"; //autoincrement
  private final static String user_id = "user_id";
  private final static String TITLE = "title";
  private final static String CONTENT = "content";

  // create table sql query
  private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "(" +
    COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT," +
    COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";

  private String CREATE_mTODO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + mTODO + "(" +
    TASK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + user_id + "TEXT" +
    TITLE + " TEXT," + CONTENT + " TEXT" + ")";

  // drop table sql query
  private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param context
   */
  public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_VER);
    this.ctx = context;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_mTODO_TABLE);

  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    //Drop User Table if exist
    db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

  }

  /**
   * This method is to create user record
   *
   * @param user
   */
  public void add(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close();
  }

  public void add(ToDo todoTask) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(TITLE, todoTask.getTitle());
    values.put(CONTENT, todoTask.getContent());
    values.put(user_id, todoTask.getUserID());
    // Inserting Row

    db.insert(mTODO, null, values);
    db.close();
  }
  public void update(ToDo todo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(TITLE, todo.getTitle());
    values.put(CONTENT, todo.getContent());

    // Inserting Row
    db.update(mTODO, values, "task_Id=" + todo.getId(), null);
    db.close();
  }

  public ToDo getTaskById(int taskid) {
    SQLiteDatabase d = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ToDo todo = new ToDo();
    String[] columns = {
      TASK_ID,
      TITLE,
      CONTENT,
      user_id
    };

    Cursor cursor = d.query(
      mTODO,
      columns,
      "task_Id = ?", //Where value
      new String[] {
        String.valueOf(taskid)
      },
      null,
      null,
      null
    );

    try {
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        todo.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TASK_ID))));
        todo.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TITLE)));
        todo.setUserID(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(user_id)));
        todo.setContent(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CONTENT)));
        // Adding user record to list

      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return todo;
  }

  public boolean checkUser(String email) {

    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
      COLUMN_USER_ID
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // selection criteria
    String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ?";

    // selection argument
    String[] selectionArgs = {
      email
    };

    // query user table with condition

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
      TABLE_USER, //Table to query
      columns, //columns to return
      selection, //columns for the WHERE clause
      selectionArgs, //The values for the WHERE clause
      null, //group the rows
      null, //filter by row groups
      null); //The sort order
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    if (cursorCount > 0) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  /**
   * This method to check user exist or not
   */
  public long checkUser(String email, String password) {

    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
      COLUMN_USER_ID
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    // selection criteria
    String selection = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " = ? " + " AND " + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ?";

    // selection arguments
    String[] selectionArgs = {
      email,
      password
    };

    // query user table with conditions

    long userid = 0;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
      columns, //columns to return
      selection, //columns for the WHERE clause
      selectionArgs, //The values for the WHERE clause
      null, //group the rows
      null, //filter by row groups
      null); //The sort order

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

    if (cursorCount > 0) {
      userid = cursor.getLong(0);
      cursor.close();
      db.close();
      return userid;
    }

    return 0;

  }
  public void deleteRow(ToDo todo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // delete user record by id
    db.delete(mTODO, TASK_ID + " = ?", new String[] {
      String.valueOf(todo.getId())
    });
    db.close();
  }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
private String CREATE_mTODO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + mTODO + "("
    + TASK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + user_id + "TEXT"
```

Mind your whitespace between column names and types:

```
                                                                  ^
```

After adding the missing space, you can uninstall your app to recreate the database.